# turn on laser pointer in powerpoint with add ins

Tags: c#, add-in, powerpoint

how can i turn my mouse cursor to laser pointer on powerpoint2010 slideshow with an addins .
[image]
by default cursor changes by hloding down Ctrl+LeftMouseKey in SlideShow Mode.
but i want change that by add in code,
i found a property (PointerType) but it not accept somthing like laserPointer:

```
Application.Presentations[1].SlideShowWindow.View.PointerType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowPointerType.ppSlideShowPointerPen;
```

or can we do it with dirty way :) like keep Ctrl+LeftMouseKey down by code ? 
ty

Comment: Explain the reason that line of code didn't work?

Comment: this Works,But it Change Pointer to Pen Pointer (a little red circle), but i want change to LaserPointer like linked image;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2013 its possible:

```
((dynamic)pWindow.View).LaserPointerEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it's Ctrl + LeftMouseKey that produces the laser pointer, and it's not a toggle the way the other settings are; the laser pointer appears only while Ctrl+LeftMouse are pressed.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the object model relating to this, so other than somehow toggling the Ctrl and LeftMouse to ON via code, I don't think you can do it.

Comment: ty for answer , but what u refer to do somthing like that ?

Comment: Toggling the keys on by code, do you mean?  Afraid I don't know.  That would be more of a Windows/Mac API question than one specific to PowerPoint, so reposting the questino with different tags might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do these but you can use a windows form with transparent background and do what you want there . :))
you can use cursor property to show what u want